# Deallocate a port on mac for zookeeper

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, port, apache-zookeeper

I know this might have asked before. But I have been struggling with this for last 2 hours.

I am following a tutorial on apache kafka and trying to run this command to run a docker container:

```
docker run --rm -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081-8083:8081-8083 -p 9581-9585:9581-9585 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=192.168.99.100            landoop/fast-data-dev:latest
```

however I am getting this error:

```
ocker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint friendly_austin
 (7fe43e4a4081d4ac072a8fbb9582b9456eb71e488fe9a21c358a916061709005): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:2181 failed: port is already allocated.
```

I am aware this has to do with the allocated port 2181.

So i ran

```
lsof -i TCP:2181
```

I got the following pid:

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    79831 omkar   27u  IPv6 0xa390d90220637c69      0t0  TCP *:eforward (LISTEN)
```

However, I dont understand how can i free this port, or deallocate it? DO i even need to do it?

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a docker error - you cannot map port 2181 of your container as your host already use it

Simply modify this binding:

```
docker run --rm -p 2182:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081-8083:8081-8083 -p 9581-9585:9581-9585 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=192.168.99.100            landoop/fast-data-dev:latest
```

note the -p **2182**:2181

I used 2182 here, you can use an other one
If you ever need to use zookeeper adress, this will be via :2182